# How do you start mist from the command line in linux

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, mist, linux

I'm on Linux Mint 18.2 (built on Ubuntu, using the Cinnamon desktop). I've installed mist successfully, and I can start it from the "Menu->Other->Ethereum Wallet" icon in the start menu, but I cannot yet figure out how to start it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I should have dug a little deeper first. From the command prompt

```
> ethereumwallet
```

I just got confused, since the tool is called mist. I found this by right clicking on the "Menu" button, click "Configure", click the "Menu" tab, click "Open the menu editor", click on "Other" then "Ethereum Wallet" and then properties - which shows you the location of the program and the name of it.